# Describe the equivalence class

Tags: discrete-mathematics

> Let  $A=\{x\in \Bbb N | 1 \le x \le 20\}$. Define a relation on $A$ by $x\sim y$ if and only if $5$ divides $x-y$. Describe in detail the equivalence classes.

I thought there are only $5$ equivalent classes, which includes

$[0]=\{5,10,15, 20\}$
$[1]=\{6, 11, 16\}$
$[2]=\{7, 12, 17\}$
$[3]=\{8, 13, 18\}$
$[4]=\{9, 14, 19\}$

I don't understand why this is wrong. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Well, the first one is not called "$[0]$" because $0\notin A$. Perhaps you should call it $[10]$, or $[15]$ or whatever. More importantly, for some reason you did not put $1\in[1]$, $2\in[2]$ et cetera.

Comment: You are right, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$[1]=\{ 1,6,11,16\}$$

Can you fix the mistake now?

Comment: Yes. Thank you. Does that mean there are 20 different equivalence class?

Comment: There are only $5$. You didn't include some elements inside your original solution. For example, you forget to include $1$ inside $[1]$.

Comment: I got this. Thank you.